# Flutter page navigation lagging

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter, dart

I notficed that my app gets laggy after when I navigate to different pages. Also, when I tried switching from one page to another many time back and forth, the app gets laggy. Other apps can hadle rapid and continuous page switches, how can do that?

This is the way I navigate between pages:

```
Future<Widget> buildChatPage() async {
    return Future.microtask(() {
        return ChatPage();
    });
  }

var page = await buildChatPage();
                await Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => 
                    page
                  ), (Route<dynamic> route) => false
                );
```

These are the lags I am talking about
[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix5WE.gif)

I want to remove lags and make the navigation smoother

Comment: try to run your app with
' flutter run --profile ' command

Comment: Buddhika P. De Silva tried, didn't help